# How do I get Average Volume of 5min candles at daily sesssion

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I want to build a pine script which will calculate the average 5min volume of the current trading session ie: 04:00 - 20:00
I'm struggling to define the daily session.
Should be the cumulative vol divided by the number of bars.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found it from another post.

[I want to build a pine script which will give me Relative volume per minute in 15 min chart compare with previous day candle of same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581172/i-want-to-build-a-pine-script-which-will-give-me-relative-volume-per-minute-in-1)

Thank you!

```
//@version=5
indicator('Number bars in session', precision=2, format=format.volume)

timeAllowed = input("0930-1600", session.extended)

// Check to see if we are in allowed hours using session info on all 7 days of the week. 
timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":23456")


numBars = 0

t = time('D')

if timeIsAllowed  
    if t == t[1] 
        numBars := nz(numBars[1]) + 1
        numBars
    else
        numBars := 1
        numBars
    
    
    
total_volume = 0.0

for i = 0 to numBars by 1
    total_volume += volume[i]
    total_volume
    
    
Avol = (total_volume / numBars)/15
    
    
plot(Avol)
plot(numBars)
```